# getting values from a numpy array between two points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an image stored in a 2D numpy array. I want to extract all pixel values in a rectangle from that array. The rectangle is defined as `((x1,y1),(x2,y2))` where all x and y s are naturally array indices.

I can extract the pixel values using a nested for loop, but what would be a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use slicing.  For example:

```
In [3]: a = numpy.arange(20).reshape((4,5))

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [5]: a[2:4, 3:5]
Out[5]: 
array([[13, 14],
       [18, 19]])
```

In general, you can replace an index with a slice where slices have the form start:stop or, optionally, start:stop:step and variables are allowed:

```
In [6]: x=2 ; print a[x-1:x+1, :]
[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [numpy's indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
import numpy
array = numpy.arange(24).reshape((4, 6))
indices = ((1, 3), (2, 5))

((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) = indices
result = array[x1:x2, y1:y2]
```